# Writing To a Binary File

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles, stl-format

I am attempting to write an STL Binary file in Fortran 90. The file has the following format

> HEADER: An 80 byte ASCII header - TITLE
>
> A 4 byte unsigned long integer, NO. OF FACETS
>
> FORMAT FOR EACH FACET:
>
> Normal vector, 3 floating values of 4 bytes each;
>
> Vertex 1 XYZ coordinates, 3 floating values of 4 bytes each;
>
> Vertex 2 XYZ coordinates, 3 floating values of 4 bytes each;
>
> Vertex 3 XYZ coordinates, 3 floating values of 4 bytes each;
>
> An unsigned integer, of 2 bytes, that should be zero;

I am attempting to create an unformatted file for writing the relevant information but am having trouble defining the correct record length. Assuming that I have N facets, I am using the following commands to open and write information

```
open(unit = 1, status = 'replace', iostat = ioerror, format = 'unformatted', access = 'direct', recl = 84 + N * 50, file = 'c:\temp\test.stl')
```

Can I issue the first write statement to write out the header information followed by the second write statement (within a do loop) to write out the facet information?

If so, what would be the record number I need to have for each of the write statements since I have the header and the facet information with different record lengths.

```
write(1,rec=?), *header information*
do,i=1,N,1
   write(1,rec=?), *facet information*
enddo
```

Comment: Are you sure that a Fortran unformatted direct access file is appropriate for this?

Comment: Direct access seems to be a bad design choice. Stream would be much better, considering the header. How did you get the `recl = 84 + N * 50`? The inquire statement should be used for that.

Comment: Since the records are of different lengths, direct access is inappropriate, as already commented.

Comment: If you had to do without streams, you could write the entire file as a single record. That means one write, header and all. Note the recl unit is typically 4 bytes, so divide that expression by 4 and you have a problem if n is odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was interesting. I have hacked together a small program that creates a very simple pyramid using the `STREAM` access. It seems to work:

```fortran
program write_stl
    use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: u = 400
    character(len=*), parameter :: fname = 'pyramid.stl'
    integer :: ios
    integer(kind=int32) :: num_facets
    character(len=80) :: title
    real(kind=real32), dimension(3) :: top_vertex, front_vertex, left_vertex, right_vertex

    top_vertex = (/0.0, 0.0, 2.0/)
    front_vertex = (/0.0, -1.0, 0.0/)
    left_vertex = (/-1.0, 1.0, 0.0/)
    right_vertex = (/1.0, 1.0, 0.0/)

    open(unit=u, file=fname, access='stream', status='replace', &
        action='write', iostat=ios)
    call check(ios, 'open')

    title = "Testpyramid"
    write(u, iostat=ios) title
    call check(ios, 'write title')
    num_facets = 4
    write(u, iostat=ios) num_facets
    call check(ios, 'write number of facets')
    ! bottom facet
    call write_facet(u, front_vertex, left_vertex, right_vertex)
    call write_facet(u, top_vertex, right_vertex, left_vertex)
    call write_facet(u, top_vertex, left_vertex, front_vertex)
    call write_facet(u, top_vertex, front_vertex, right_vertex)

    close(u, iostat=ios)
    call check(ios, 'close')

contains

    subroutine check(ios, operation)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: ios
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: operation
        if (ios == 0) return
        write(*, '(A, I0, 2A)') "Encountered error ", ios, " while performing ", operation
        stop 1
    end subroutine check

    subroutine write_facet(u, vertex1, vertex2, vertex3)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: u
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3), intent(in) :: vertex1, vertex2, vertex3
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3) :: normal
        integer(kind=int16), parameter :: zero = 0

        normal = calc_normal(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3)
        write(u, iostat=ios) normal
        call check(ios, 'write normal')
        write(u, iostat=ios) vertex1
        call check(ios, 'write vertex')
        write(u, iostat=ios) vertex2
        call check(ios, 'write vertex')
        write(u, iostat=ios) vertex3
        call check(ios, 'write vertex')
        write(u, iostat=ios) zero
        call check(ios, 'write zero')
    end subroutine write_facet

    function calc_normal(vec1, vec2, vec3)
        implicit none
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3), intent(in) :: vec1, vec2, vec3
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3) :: calc_normal
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3) :: d1, d2
        d1 = vec2 - vec1
        d2 = vec3 - vec1
        calc_normal(1) = d1(2) * d2(3) - d1(3) * d2(2)
        calc_normal(2) = d1(3) * d2(1) - d1(1) * d2(3)
        calc_normal(3) = d1(1) * d2(2) - d1(2) * d2(1)
        calc_normal = calc_normal / norm(calc_normal)
    end function calc_normal

    function norm(vec)
        implicit none
        real(kind=real32), dimension(3), intent(in) :: vec
        real(kind=real32) :: norm

        norm = sqrt(vec(1)**2 + vec(2)**2 + vec(3)**2)
    end function norm

end program write_stl
```

Comment: Thanks chw21 for the example!  Guess I was heading down the wrong path with writing as an unformatted file as several of you pointed out.